# Import declarations in a namespace from external module

Tags: import, module, typescript, external, internal

I would like use [TypeScript.NET](https://github.com/electricessence/TypeScript.NET) in my angular application. I am newbie in typescript and maybe root of problem is simple.

For example I would like to use [StringBuilder](http://electricessence.github.io/TypeScript.NET/documentation/modules/_system_text_stringbuilder_.html).

First I install TypeScript via [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TypeScript.NET.Library/)

Add ref to index.html

```
<script src="source/System/Text/StringBuilder.js"></script>  
<script src="source/System/Text/Utility.js"></script>
```

Here I am confuse, I don’t use any module system (e.g commonJs, amd, etc).
TypeScript.NET nuget add to my project folder **dist** which constains probably dist version for amd, commonjs etc hence I reference files from **source** folder.

Now I want to use **StringBuilder** in my **internal module**.

```
module App.Company{
    //in internal module
    import IVersion = App.IVersion; 
    import IError = App.IError;

    //TypeScript.NET
    import StringBuilder from "../../../../source/system/text/stringbuilder";
}
```

Here I get compilation errror

```
Import declarations in a namespace cannot reference a module
```

What is solution?

Second how can simple reference all types from TypeScript.NET?

Comment: I'm not familiar with .NET, but I think you should [`<reference />`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Namespaces%20and%20Modules.md#-reference-ing-a-module) instead of `import`.

Comment: After you reference that file, you should have access to all the globals it exposes without importing. [See their docs here to see what those globals are.](http://electricessence.github.io/TypeScript.NET/documentation/globals.html)

Comment: @Louy I tried add /// <reference path="../../../../source/system/text/stringbuilder.ts" /> not work.

Comment: You must reference a `.d.ts` file, not a regular `.ts` file.

Comment: stringbuilder.d.ts is missing, when added nuget Typescript.NET it does not contains stringbuilder.d.ts.

Comment: Oh apparently they haven't added those files. I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/electricessence/TypeScript.NET/issues/29).

Comment: You should put your import statement abode your namespace declaration.